# Shanken's correction for Fama-MacBeth (1973) generalization of the CAPM

Tags: asset-pricing, factor-models, capm, econometrics

Fama & MacBeth (1973) tested the CAPM against an alternative that the dependence between the expected excess return $E(r_{i,t}^∗)$ and the relative systematic risk $\beta_$ is nonlinear (namely, quadratic) and that the idiosyncratic risk $\sigma_i$ commands nonzero expected return. The corresponding cross-sectional regression is (using different notation from the original, but keeping the equation number for reference)
$$
r_{i,t}^∗ = \lambda_0 + \lambda_1 \beta_i + \lambda_2 \beta_i^2 + \lambda_3 \sigma_i + u_{i,t}. \tag{7}
$$
Since $\beta_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are not observed, a two-stage procedure is used where $\beta_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are first estimated from time-series regressions and then their fitted values are used in cross-sectional regressions (one for every time period) of the type specified above.

I am wondering about **how to obtain Shanken's correction** for the fact that fitted values $\hat\beta_i$ and $\hat\sigma_i$ are used instead of the true, unobservable $\beta_i$ and $\sigma_i$.

- For the CAPM or a multifactor model like the Fama-French 3 factor (FF3f) one, the variance of the risk premium estimate should be of the shape provided by Goyal (2012) in Eq. (33):
  $$
  T\cdot\mathrm{var}_{\mathrm{EIV}}(\hat{\lambda})=(1+c)[T\cdot\mathrm{var}(\hat{\lambda})-\Sigma_F]+\Sigma_F. \tag{33}
  $$
  I believe $\hat\lambda$ excludes $\hat\lambda_0$. I skip the explanation of the other symbols out of laziness.
- However, I am not sure $(33)$ can be applied directly to $(7)$ since it is a bit special:
  (1) $\beta_i^2$ enters nonlinearly and,
  (2) unlike factor sensitivities such as $\beta_i$ in the CAPM or the ones in the FF3f model, $\sigma_i$ is not obtained as a slope coefficient in a time-series regression but rather as the standard deviation of residuals from such a regression.
  And even if $(33)$ were to apply directly to $(7)$, what would I take as the factor corresponding to $\lambda_3$ for estimating $\Sigma_F$?

So how does Shanken's correction look like for $(7)$?

**References:**

- Fama, E. F., & MacBeth, J. D. (1973). Risk, return, and equilibrium: Empirical tests. *Journal of Political Economy, 81*(3), 607-636.
- Goyal, A. (2012). Empirical cross-sectional asset pricing: a survey. *Financial Markets and Portfolio Management, 26*(1), 3-38.
- Shanken, J. (1992). On the Estimation of Beta-Pricing Models. *Review of Financial Studies, 5*(1), 1-33.